Cross origin redirect sign-in on Google Chrome M115+ is no longer supported, and will stop working on June 24, 2024, Flutter - Firebase
I am using firebase phone authentication with otp, but i can't login to my app due to this:

Cross origin redirect sign-in on Google Chrome M115+ is no longer supported, and will stop working on June 24, 2024.

Migrate to an alternative solution before June 24, 2024
End-users can continue to sign in to your app until June 24, 2024
This is already required on Firefox 109+ and Safari 16.1+


This is my code:
void sendOtp() async {
    String phoneNumber = phoneController.text.trim();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    setState(() {
      if (phoneNumber.length > 9) _isLoading = 1;
      _validate = phoneNumber.length <= 9;
    });
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {},
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException exception) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = 0;
        });
        Dialogs.showErrorSnackBar(context, exception.message!);
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = 2;
        });
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    OTPScreen(verificationId: verificationId)));
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
      phoneNumber: '+${selectedCountry.phoneCode}$phoneNumber',
    );
  }

Earlier, this code is redirecting me to google chrome for reCAPTCHA verification and working fine. But now it's showing error:

This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.

